# Create Groups from a list of Objects in C#

Tags: c#, list, grouping

I Have a list of objects called Team and I want to create groups of them but not in order, randomized. The groups number is given to the function as well as the list

```
public List<List<Team>> GenerateGroups(List<Team> teams, int amount)
{
    List<List<Team>> result = new List<List<Team>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i)
        result.Add(new List<Team>());
    foreach(Team team in teams)
    {
        //Add something           
    }
    return result;
}
```

i got stuck here. I am not sure how to add the teams. Also if someone can condense my code, it will be pretty helpful. I don't need it to return List> if someone has a better idea.

Comment: Do the groups have to be equal size?

Comment: `static Random rnd = new Random();
var randomObjectIndex = rnd.Next(list.Count);
var FinallList<t>.Add(list[randomObjectIndex])`

Way to get random object from list

Comment: @KevinLee No because I will need to add extra restritions for the teams and amount variables. I try to make it work for now.

Comment: @MKasprzyk the list of objects are predefined. I want them placed at random.

Comment: GroupBy random ? `Random random = new Random(); teams.GroupBy(p => random.Next(amount))`. Note that a [secure random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) is better than Random and Guids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one gives random groups without duplicates:

```
private static Random _rnd = new Random();

private static Team GetAndRemoveRandomTeam(List<Team> allTeams)
{
    int randomIndex = _rnd.Next(allTeams.Count);
    Team randomTeam = allTeams[randomIndex];
    allTeams.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
    return randomTeam;
}

public static List<List<Team>> GenerateGroups(List<Team> teams, int amount)
{
    int teamCount = (int) teams.Count/amount;
    List<Team> allteams = teams.ToList(); // copy to be able to remove items

    if (teamCount == 0)
        return new List<List<Team>> {allteams};

    List<List<Team>> allTeamGroups = new List<List<Team>>();
    List<Team> thisTeam = new List<Team>();
    while (allteams.Count > 0)
    {
        if (thisTeam.Count == amount)
        {
            allTeamGroups.Add(thisTeam);
            thisTeam = new List<Team>();
        }
        thisTeam.Add(GetAndRemoveRandomTeam(allteams));
    }
    allTeamGroups.Add(thisTeam);

    return allTeamGroups;
}
```

Comment: can you explain why in my example I might get duplicates? Thanks :)

Comment: @GiladGreen: i haven't commented your answer, but f.e. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38589813/284240) answer has duplciates.

Comment: Ah sorry them :) I thought I missed it and did actually have dups

Comment: This answer works but the other one is done in one line.

Comment: @DimitrisKaragiannis: sure. I normally also like LINQ. But in this case i'd prefer this method because it's easier to read(?), maintain, debug and to log. If indexes matter i often prefer non-LINQ solutions. In general a lower line-count is not a sign of quality or even performance.

Answer (score 7):

This will order your `teams` randomly and then put them in groups. The number of output groups in the list is according to the `amount` parameter:

```
public static List<List<Team>> GenerateGroups(List<Team> teams, int amount)
{
    return teams.OrderBy(item => Guid.NewGuid())
            .Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, GroupIndex = index % amount })
            .GroupBy(item => item.GroupIndex, 
                     (key, group) => group.Select(groupItem => groupItem.Item).ToList())
            .ToList();
}
```

---

One can also random using the `Random` class but I would use it to create the order and not `group by` it. Like this:

```
public static List<List<Team>> GenerateGroups(List<Team> teams, int amount)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    return teams.OrderBy(item => random.NextDouble())
            .Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, GroupIndex = index % amount })
            .GroupBy(item => item.GroupIndex,
                     (key, group) => group.Select(groupItem => groupItem.Item).ToList())
            .ToList();
}
```

Comment: @Tonio - see my editing. I would'nt do it for the grouping because the `Random` might give me the same number twice - and then if I group by it then I will get groups of uneven size

Comment: I think your solution is good and condense. Let me test it with my code

Comment: i'd suggest `NextDouble()` to `Next(teams.Count)`, you'll get a better randomisation and i believe its also minutely more efficient

Comment: Random and Guid are fast but not as random as it should be. If you need a better quality of randomness use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` (but will be slower).

Comment: @GiladGreen yes it did and no duplicates. i even tried with a 50 object long list. I'll vote it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better for you to define `Group` class like:

```
class Group {
   List<Team> teams;
}
```

And about adding teams:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i)
            groups.Add(new Group());

        foreach(Team team in teams)
        {
            int index = rnd.Next(0, amount);
            groups[index].Add(team);
        }
        return groups;
```

Comment: That is what I will do later. For now, I am looking for the code in the brackets where you have the comments